# UnityContainer throws a null reference exception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have installed Nuget package of Unity (5.8.6).

The line of code below is giving me a null reference exception.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
```

When I see in the reference it is showing as `Unity` instead of `Microsoft.Practices.Unity`.

Please help me in resolving the issue

Comment: Please try to reproduce it in a brand new project first.

Comment: Please copy the exact exception message. What you've shown there should not throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: container.parent is coming as null. I am not getting intellisense as well.IUnityContainer is not present in Unity NuGet package 5.8.6. I added NuGet package and added above line. Its not compiling even. I am not sure what references need to be added.